# Solr throwing error when searching with special characters and camel casing

Tags: java, solr, lucene, sap-commerce-cloud

I have an issue in searching TEXT field, Here is my example:

I have product name **DRC Assortment (3xEZ, 2xGDE, 3xLT, 2xRI, 1xRC, 3xRSV)** when doing full indexing solr is throwing the error as below, but when I remove the characters inside the brackets including the brackets, the full index is successful.

> WARN  [full-frwIndex-cronJob::de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.jalo.ServicelayerJob] (full-frwIndex-cronJob) [SolrIndexerJob] Error during indexer call: frwIndex
>   de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.exceptions.IndexerException: de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.exceptions.IndexerException: **Indexer worker failed. Max number of retries in total has been reached**
>           at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.strategies.impl.DefaultIndexerStrategy.doExecute(DefaultIndexerStrategy.java:97) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
>           at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.strategies.impl.AbstractIndexerStrategy.doExecute(AbstractIndexerStrategy.java:165) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
>           at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.strategies.impl.AbstractIndexerStrategy.execute(AbstractIndexerStrategy.java:124) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
>           at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.impl.DefaultIndexerService.performFullIndex(DefaultIndexerService.java:68) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
>           at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.cron.SolrIndexerJob.indexItems(SolrIndexerJob.java:78) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
>           at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.cron.SolrIndexerJob.performIndexingJob(SolrIndexerJob.java:57) [solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
>           at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.cron.AbstractIndexerJob.perform(AbstractIndexerJob.java:40) [solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.jalo.ServicelayerJob.performCronJob(ServicelayerJob.java:38) [processingserver.jar:?]
>           at de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.Job.execute(Job.java:1390) [processingserver.jar:?]
>           at de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.Job.performImpl(Job.java:814) [processingserver.jar:?]
>           at de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.Job.access$1(Job.java:767) [processingserver.jar:?]
>           at de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.Job$JobRunable.run(Job.java:686) [processingserver.jar:?]
>           at de.hybris.platform.util.threadpool.PoolableThread.internalRun(PoolableThread.java:208) [coreserver.jar:?]
>           at de.hybris.platform.core.threadregistry.RegistrableThread.run(RegistrableThread.java:135) [coreserver.jar:?]
>   Caused by: de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.exceptions.IndexerException: Indexer worker failed. Max number of retries in total has been reached
>           at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.strategies.impl.DefaultIndexerStrategy.runWorkers(DefaultIndexerStrategy.java:154) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
>           at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.strategies.impl.DefaultIndexerStrategy.doExecute(DefaultIndexerStrategy.java:93) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
>           ... 13 more
>   Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at https://localhost:8983/solr: **Exception writing document id frwProductCatalog/Online/171377-15417
>   25 to the index; possible analysis error: startOffset must be non-negative, and endOffset must be >= startOffset, and offsets must not go backwards startOffset=45,endOffset=49,lastStartOffset=46 for field 'allFields_text_en'**
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
>           at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.strategies.impl.DefaultIndexerStrategy.runWorkers(DefaultIndexerStrategy.java:141) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
>           at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.strategies.impl.DefaultIndexerStrategy.doExecute(DefaultIndexerStrategy.java:93) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
>           ... 13 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at https://localhost:8983/solr: Exception writing document id frwProductCatalog/Online/171377-1541725 to the index; possible analysis error:
>    **startOffset must be non-negative, and endOffset must be >= startOffset, and offsets must not go backwards startOffset=45,endOffset=49,lastStartOffset=46 for field 'allFields_text_en'**
>           at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:627) ~[solr-solrj-7.0.0.jar:7.0.0 3ba304b29825a94249c5145b3f5061e87b87d8f8 - anshum - 2017-09-08 13:21:09]
>           at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:253) ~[solr-solrj-7.0.0.jar:7.0.0 3ba304b29825a94249c5145b3f5061e87b87d8f8 - anshum - 2017-09-08 13:21:09]
>           at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:242) ~[solr-solrj-7.0.0.jar:7.0.0 3ba304b29825a94249c5145b3f5061e87b87d8f8 - anshum - 2017-09-08 13:21:09]
>           at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.solr.impl.SolrStandaloneSearchProvider$ClusterSolrClient.request(SolrStandaloneSearchProvider.java:511) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
>           at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.solr.impl.CachedSolrClient.request(CachedSolrClient.java:72) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:178) ~[solr-solrj-7.0.0.jar:7.0.0 3ba304b29825a94249c5145b3f5061e87b87d8f8 - anshum - 2017-09-08 13:21:09]
>           at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:106) ~[solr-solrj-7.0.0.jar:7.0.0 3ba304b29825a94249c5145b3f5061e87b87d8f8 - anshum - 2017-09-08 13:21:09]
>           at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:71) ~[solr-solrj-7.0.0.jar:7.0.0 3ba304b29825a94249c5145b3f5061e87b87d8f8 - anshum - 2017-09-08 13:21:09]
>           at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.impl.SolrServerExporter.exportToUpdateIndex(SolrServerExporter.java:89) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
>           at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.impl.DefaultIndexer.indexItems(DefaultIndexer.java:130) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
>           at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.strategies.impl.DefaultIndexerBatchStrategy.executeIndexerOperation(DefaultIndexerBatchStrategy.java:253) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
>           at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.strategies.impl.DefaultIndexerBatchStrategy.execute(DefaultIndexerBatchStrategy.java:218) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
>           at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.workers.impl.DefaultIndexerWorker.doRun(DefaultIndexerWorker.java:202) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
>           at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.workers.impl.DefaultIndexerWorker.run(DefaultIndexerWorker.java:158) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:1.8.0_144]

My `schema.xml` for `text`, `text_gen`, `text_en` as below :

```
    <fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.ManagedSynonymFilterFactory" managed="en" />
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" />
            <filter class="solr.ManagedStopFilterFactory" managed="en" />
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"  preserveOriginal="1"
                generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1"
                catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" />
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1"
                catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" preserveOriginal="1"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <!--
        A general unstemmed text field - good if one does not know the
        language of the field
    -->
    <fieldType name="textgen" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1"
                catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" preserveOriginal="1"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Can you please let me know what am i missing?

Comment: Can you share with as `allFields_text_en` configuration if that exists in your `schema.xml`?

Comment: Thanks for coming back, allfields is the qualifier name and hybris appends the qualifier name to field name before query/indexing. allFields_text_en does not exist in the schema.xml

Comment: Issue sorted when adding splitOnNumerics="0" to schema.xml

Comment: `splitOnNumerics="0"`  is used to prevent using numbers as Splitters for String/text values when Indexing/Quering. Could you add an answer if that resolve the issue. That can help other people.

Comment: Yes, that's the exact issue I have faced with my above search text. When i use this splitOnNumerics="0" it doesn't split the number for String/text as you said and that is what I needed. Thanks for your help